# Is there a way to debug pages in UC Browser on iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, uc-browser

I have markup issues in my project in UC Browser from App Store but I have not found way to connect to Developer Tools.
Is there a way to connect some devTools( Chrome, Safari, etc) to mobile device?

Comment: UC browser is based out of webkit but its works as proxy browser, where is page get rendered remotely then compressed and sent to the actual device. So, in iOS devices there will be some difference.